# Mongodb , NodeJS CPU keeps on increasing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

We're having a problem where every once in a while one of our environments our node app runs on 100% CPU. The server isn't very active and usually runs on 0%-2% CPU. I was wondering what are the common issues that might cause this problem and what would be the best way to find out what causing this issue.

below code on Server side code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
const fs = require('fs');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3110;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("connected");
  MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
 
  socket.broadcast.on('getMessages', function (msg) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      if (err) throw err;
       console.log(msg)
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "roomId": msg["roomId"] }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(parseInt(msg["limit"])).skip(parseInt(msg["total"])).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result.slice().reverse().forEach(element => {
          io.to(socket.id).emit(msg["roomId"], element);
        });
        //db.close;
      });
  });


  socket.broadcast.on('getMessages_once', function (msg) {
   // MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(msg)
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "roomId": msg["roomId"] }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(parseInt(msg["limit"])).skip(parseInt(msg["total"])).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.length);
        io.to(socket.id).emit(msg["roomId"] + "_once", result.reverse());
        // result.slice().reverse().forEach(element => {

        // });
        //db.close;
      });
    //});
  });

  //---- send message to from client--///
  socket.broadcast.on('sendMessage', function (msg) {
    //MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      if (err) throw err;
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).insertOne(msg["data"], function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var messsageData = {
          "roomId": msg["roomId"],
          "messageId": msg["messageId"],
          "collectionName": "conversations"
        };
        getMessageCount(messsageData);
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        msg["limit"] = "1";
        msg["total"] = "0";

        var val = { $set: msg["lastMessage"] };
        var Ids = { "roomId": msg["roomId"] };
        dbo.collection("conversations").findOneAndUpdate(Ids, val, { upsert: true }, function (err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;

          var FullArray = res["value"]["userList"];

          FullArray.forEach(element => {
            var someString = element;
            someString["collectionName"] = "conversations";
            MemberList(someString);
          });
        });

        dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "roomId": msg["roomId"] }, { limit: 1 }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          result.forEach(element => {
            io.emit(msg["roomId"], element);
          });
          //db.close;
        });
      });
    //});
  });



  //-- add user to database -----///
  socket.broadcast.on('createUser', function (msg) {
    console.log("createUser");
    //MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "userId": msg["userId"], "title": msg["title"] }).toArray(function (err, result) {
         console.log(result);
        if (result.length == 0) {
          dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).insertOne(msg, function (err, converRes) {
            console.log(converRes);
            //db.close;
          });
        }
        else {
          //db.close;
        }
      });
    //});
  });



  // --------   create Room   ----///
  socket.broadcast.on('createRoom', function (msg) {
    //console.log("createRoom");
   // MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      var dataObject = msg["data"];
      var roomid = dataObject["roomId"];
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "roomId": roomid }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (result.length == 0) {
          dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).insertOne(msg["data"], function (err, converRes) {
            // console.log(converRes["insertedId"]);
            io.emit('roomId', converRes["insertedId"]);
            //db.close;
          });
        }
        else {
          //db.close;
        }
      });
   // });
  });


  //---- get member list --////
  socket.on('getChatUserList', function (msg) {
    MemberList(msg);
  });

  function MemberList(msg) {
    //MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      if (err) throw err;
      var nameTopost = msg["userId"] + "_" + msg["title"];

      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "userList.userId": msg["userId"], "userList.title": msg["title"] }).limit(parseInt(msg["limit"])).skip(parseInt(msg["total"])).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var userIdlist = [];
        result.forEach(element => {
          var someObject = element["userList"];

          someObject.forEach(obj => {
            userIdlist.push(obj)
          });
        });


        dbo.collection("users").find({ $or: userIdlist }).toArray(function (err, userData) {
          //console.log(userData);
          var someData = {
            "RoomList": result,
            "userData": userData,
          };
          //console.log(someData);
          io.emit(nameTopost, someData);
          //db.close;
        });

      });

   // });
  }


  ///----- get total message count ----/////
  socket.on('getTotalCount', function (msg) {
    getTotalCount(msg);
  });


  ///----- set total message count ----/////
  socket.on('setTotalCount', function (msg) {
    //MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      var val = { $set: msg };
      var Ids = { "totalCountId": msg["totalCountId"] };
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).findOneAndUpdate(Ids, val, { upsert: true }, function (err, res) {
        getTotalCount(msg);
      });
    //});
  });



  function getTotalCount(msg) {
    //MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "totalCountId": msg["totalCountId"] }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        io.emit(msg["totalCountId"], result[0]);
        //db.close;
      });
    //});
  }



  socket.on('getMessageCount', function (msg) {
    getMessageCount(msg);
  });


  function getMessageCount(msg) {
   // MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).find({ "roomId": msg["roomId"] }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        io.emit(msg["messageId"], result[0]);
        //db.close;
      });
   // });
  }

  socket.on('setMessageCount', function (msg) {
   // MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("Hitesh");
      var val = { $set: msg["data"] };
      var Ids = { "roomId": msg["roomId"] };
      dbo.collection(msg["collectionName"]).findOneAndUpdate(Ids, val, { upsert: true }, function (err, res) {
        //db.close
        getMessageCount(msg);
      });
   // });
  });

  });
});




http.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

....
.....
...
...
...
I am not sure whats causing this issue

[image: Following is the CPU usage]

Comment: How are the clients you are making for every connection closed?

Comment: inside andriod and ios application when the app enter background then closes the connection @D.SM

Comment: So you are not closing the clients? Explains the resource leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are creating a new mongo connection on every new socket connection:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("connected");
  MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
```

You should rather create a single connection and share that. I would normally create a connection to the db and **then** start the HTTP and socket server.

Snippet using mongoose but concept is the same - open the connection, then setup server and handlers:

```
mongoose.connect(`${config.db.uri}/${config.db.database}`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, autoIndex: false});
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => {
    const app = express();

    app.db = db;
    ...

    const http = require('http').createServer(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(http);
    ...

    http.listen(config.server.port, () => {
       console.log(`listening on ${config.server.port}`);
    });

    ...
```